My if statement seems to be incorrect, how can I improve my code?
print()
user = input(f"Put in your name to see if your able to respond:")
print()

banned_users = ["Arnold" 'Leslie' 'Jacob' 'Rick']

if user not in banned_users:
    print(f"{user.title()},you can post a response if you wish")
else:
    print(f"{banned_users},you are banned!")

    print()

    print()

I have written this code below however whenever I type in the banned users name such as 'Arnold' it replies back with 'you can post a response if you wish', even though I have stated in the code whoever is listed in banned users should respond back with 'you are banned' does anyone know why this is happening?

You need commas between the names. Right now it's a list with one long string.

Try print(banned_users) to see what's wrong.

In Python (but not only), "foo" "bar" is the same as "foobar".

By the way I suggest you replace all the names to lower case and do user = user.lower() before the if to avoid case issues.

You forgot to put commas between the names of banned users.
banned_users = ['Arnold', 'Leslie', 'Jacob', 'Rick']

